# SubMenu close on the selecting the link

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to work on the responsive navbar with on-click dropdown menu (which I am referring to submenu hereafter).

I am able to close the submenu on click outside the submenu. The problem is after the link in the submenu is clicked, the submenu does not get closed. I believe I know the problem as well. It is because I have used the state variable 'subMenuOpen' to control when it is to be opened or closed. So, after clicking a link in the submenu, this state variable is not getting false, so it stays open. But I do not know how to change this state variable to true, without affecting the responsiveness.

I would appreciate if someone help me on this. I am using styled component and avoiding to use any className.

My Header.js file is as follows:

```
import {
  HeaderContainer,
  HeaderLogo,
  ImageLogo,
  SearchWrapper,
  Input,
  SearchText,
  MenuIcon,
  MenuContainer,
  Button,
  SubMenuContainer,
  SubMenuLinkContainer,
  SubMenuLink,
  MenuLinkContainer,
  MenuLink,
  MenuSubLinkContainer,
  MenuSubLink,
} from "./HeaderStyles";

import logo from "../../../assets/logo.svg";
import { headerDataOption1, headerDataOption2 } from "./HeaderData";
import { useRef, useState, useEffect, createRef } from "react";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faBars, faXmark } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const Header = () => {
  const [isRegistered, setIsRegistered] = useState(false);

  const [showIconMenu, setShowIconMenu] = useState(false);

  const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(false); // state variable to open and close the "Categories" sub-menu

  let ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const closeSubMenu = (e) => {
      if (subMenuOpen && ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setSubMenuOpen(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", closeSubMenu);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", closeSubMenu);

    return () => {
      // cleanup the event listener
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", closeSubMenu);
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", closeSubMenu);
    };
  }, [subMenuOpen]);

  const menuHandler = () => {
    setShowIconMenu(!showIconMenu);
  };

  console.log("Menu Icon State:", showIconMenu);

  return (
    <HeaderContainer>
      <HeaderLogo to="/">
        <ImageLogo src={logo} alt="logo" />
      </HeaderLogo>

      <SearchWrapper>
        <Input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        <SearchText>Search</SearchText>
      </SearchWrapper>

      <MenuIcon>
        {showIconMenu ? (
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark} onClick={menuHandler} />
        ) : (
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} onClick={menuHandler} />
        )}
      </MenuIcon>

      <MenuContainer showMenu={showIconMenu}>
        {headerDataOption1.map((menu, index) =>
          menu.subCategory ? (
            <>
              <Button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                  setSubMenuOpen(!subMenuOpen);
                }}
                key={index}
              >
                {menu.name}
              </Button>
              {subMenuOpen && (
                <SubMenuContainer ref={ref}>
                  {menu.subCategory.map((submenu, index) => (
                    <SubMenuLinkContainer key={index}>
                      <SubMenuLink to={submenu.to}>{submenu.name}</SubMenuLink>
                    </SubMenuLinkContainer>
                  ))}
                </SubMenuContainer>
              )}
            </>
          ) : (
            <MenuLink to={menu.to} key={index}>
              {menu.name}
            </MenuLink>
          )
        )}
      </MenuContainer>
    </HeaderContainer>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

My style component, given by HeaderStyles.js, is as follows:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

import { Container } from "../../../GlobalStyle";

export const HeaderContainer = styled(Container)`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
`;

export const HeaderLogo = styled(NavLink)`
  @media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const ImageLogo = styled.img``;

export const SearchWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  /* border: 1px solid blue; */

  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    width: 45%;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    width: 70%;
  }
`;

export const Input = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.5);
`;

export const SearchText = styled.span`
  position: absolute;
  /* height: 80%; */
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto 0;
`;

export const MenuIcon = styled.div`
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  /* position: absolute; */
  display: none;
  z-index: 200000;

  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    display: unset;
    /* display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    z-index: 2000;
  }
`;

export const MenuContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  gap: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;

  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 1000;

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: rgba(47, 35, 82, 0.8);
    //#2f2352;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    opacity: ${({ showMenu }) => (showMenu ? 1 : 0)};
    visibility: ${({ showMenu }) => (showMenu ? "visible" : "hidden")};
    transform: translateY(${({ showMenu }) => (showMenu ? "0" : "-100vh")});
  }
`;

export const Button = styled.button`
  color: #551a9a;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;

  &:hover {
    color: #000;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    color: white;
  }
`;

export const SubMenuContainer = styled.ul`
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 130px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-radius: 10px;

  .active {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    position: unset;
  }
`;

export const SubMenuLinkContainer = styled.li`
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 25px;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #cfcfcf;

    &:first-child {
      border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    }

    &:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    }
  }
`;

export const SubMenuLink = styled(NavLink)`
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  /* letter-spacing: 0.1rem; */
`;

export const MenuLinkContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;

  .active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 8px;
  }
`;

export const MenuLink = styled(NavLink)`
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;

  &:hover {
    color: #000;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    color: white;
  }
`;
```

The menu for the Header.js is obtained from HeaderData.js, which looks:

```
export const headerDataOption1 = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    to: "/",
  },
  {
    name: "Categories",
    to: "/categories",
    subCategory: [
      { name: "All Categories", to: "/categories" },
      { name: "Inhaler", to: "/inhaler" },
      { name: "Blood Sugar", to: "/blood-sugar" },
      { name: "Pressure", to: "/pressure" },
      { name: "Personal Care", to: "/personal-care" },
      { name: "Baby Care", to: "/baby-care" },
      { name: "Vitamins & Supplements", to: "/vitamins-and-supplements" },
      { name: "Skin Care", to: "/skin-care" },
      { name: "Men's Clothing", to: "/men's-clothing" },
      { name: "Men's Shoes", to: "/men's-shoes" },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Register",
    to: "/register",
  },
  {
    name: "Login",
    to: "/login",
  },
];
```